# After configure SharePoint 2013 Web Application with FBA Auth, the Site Collection logon works only on IE

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, web-application, ntlm

After configure SharePoint 2013 Web Application with FBA Auth, the Site Collection logon works only IE. The users needs to access Site Collection with cross browser feature, but after add FBA Configuration (integrated with asp.net Membership database) the logon redirects to ID Correlation error. The Web Application uses NTLM and FBA together.

Have any idea about this?

> EDIT-Bellow follow the Log extraction based on ID Correlation error:

```
02/10/2021 21:31:41.28  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      Application error when access /default.aspx, Error=Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.  Parameter name: encodedValue   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String encodedValue)     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.ChangePasswordMenuItem.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveIn... d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:41.28* w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ...ternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:41.29  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentException: Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.  Parameter name: encodedValue    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String encodedValue)     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.ChangePasswordMenuItem.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.W... d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:41.29* w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...eb.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:41.30  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.  Parameter name: encodedValue     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String encodedValue)     at Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication.ChangePasswordMenuItem.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreR... d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:41.30* w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...enderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.Pro...  d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:41.30* w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...cessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:41.72  w3wp.exe (0x3F74)                           0x1D04  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Task: SessionManager.PerformOngoingRequestDepartures   6b6b4445-2c29-0002-b123-b4e2d09efb42

02/10/2021 21:31:41.91  w3wp.exe (0x736C)                           0x5B80  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)     
02/10/2021 21:31:42.33  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         aiaih   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion: {0}    d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.38  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         aiaih   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 02/10/2021 21:31:42.34, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion: {0}   d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.38  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.39  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x3910  SharePoint Foundation           Request Management              aeboc   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 02/10/2021 21:31:41.22, Original Level: Verbose] No data was found on the incoming client request  d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.39  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x3910  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (SPRoutingReverseProxy Get Response). Tempo de Execução=1174,83072854298    d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.39  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 agb9s,11 b4ly,16 0,18 b4ly,2 b4ly,10 8nca,11 tkau,2 ajlz0,1085 aat87 d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.40  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x57A0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://fbd101-023:8000/default.aspx)). Tempo de Execução=1175,44400613107 d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.40  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x896C  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,0 adc7u,1175 b4ly  d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184

02/10/2021 21:31:42.40  w3wp.exe (0x8AC8)                           0x896C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://fbd101-023:8000/default.aspx)). Tempo de Execução=1177,652917388   d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184
```

Comment: What does the ULS log say?

Comment: @Trevor Seward, I edited the question and write the Log based n ID Correlation `d00aaa9f-8d6a-d03c-2eb0-61f236588184`

Comment: @TrevorSeward , what do you think about the SharePoint Logs? The error output contains any suggestion of root-cause?

Comment: Hm I see you have a 3rd party full trust solution in there -- might be the issue?

Comment: @TrevorSeward, I add a 3rd party Farm Solution; I retract this, and ID Correlation Error not appear anymore; BUT, I cannot authenticate with membership user in different browsers of IE. The new behavior is: after submit logon credentials, returns to page that contains a combobox to choice authentication ("Windows Authentication" or "Forms Authentication").

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code portion (at 3rd party full trust solution) and the Site Collection returns to authenticate with Windows Authentication; BUT, at Forms Authentication continues work only in IE (like a Site Collection with FBA and NTLM without 3rd party full trust solution). I think that needs another topic to question this behavior: Why FBA Authentication works only IE? After research a lot about this topic, I get this MS Forum that mention SharePoint and another MS-Platforms that needs to be access by browser and Chrome build 80 update edition broken Cookies functionality and other items:

[Effect on SharePoint sites that use ADFS/SAML and Forms Based Authentication in Chrome version 80+](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/effect-on-sharepoint-sites-that-use-adfs-saml-and-forms-based/ba-p/1253873).

Now, I´ll try to follow this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many reasons why i do not like FBA: It's cheap, it's easy but has [tons](https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&q=sharepoint%20fba%20drawbacks) of [drawbacks](http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2009/06/13/sharepoint-fbalinks-and-limitations/). Implement [WebApplicationProxy](http://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy) or even better [AzureAD Application Proxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-proxy-enable-remote-access-sharepoint) with Kerberos Authentication instead of FBA. It will save most or all of your FBA pains.